# Drupal 7: sub-site of a multi-site

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-multi-domain

I would like to set up a multi-site in Drupal 7 and I wanted to check if it is possible to have one of the sub-site reside in a remote server? or all the sub-sites should be on the same server as the parent site?

**Update # 1:**

My scenario is more like setting up a multi-site for an organization which have several independent subsidiaries under that organization.

```
Organization (Parent site)
- Subsidiary 1 (Sub-site 1)
- Subsidiary 2 (Sub-site 2)
- Subsidiary 3 (Sub-site 3)
...
- Subsidiary n (Sub-site n)
```

So, in the above scenario every Subsidiary unit(and their Sub-site) is completely independent from one another in terms of operations or as a business unit but the functionality of the site is the same from the parent organization perspective (which is why we chose multi-site approach).

My question to you is if parent site and all the sub-sites reside on the same server:

1. How can I provide access to Subsidiary 1 to their Sub-site 1 and make sure they won't be able to access or modify anything else other than their Sub-site?
2. I would also like to be in a position to give them the freedom of doing whatever they want on their sub-site meaning letting them be on their own without causing single point of failure to the whole system or the other sub-sites?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You must have all sub-sites on the same server as the parent site.

If you are planning to setup multisite, please refer https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site

Or

You can use [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) to achieve the same.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Please see my update to my question

Comment: If you want freedom for all subsites, first approach is suitable, here you can have single code base & multiple databases.